# $(\frac{n}{e})^{n} < n! < (\frac{n}{e} + n\varepsilon)^{n}$ doesn't comply with the limit definition?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, factorial

I try to understand what I've overlooked, when I came up with this inequality:

First, we have this limit:
$$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{\frac{n!}{n^n}} = \frac{1}{e}$$
Which gives, by the definition of limit and some simple transformations:

$\frac{1}{e} - \varepsilon < \sqrt[n]{\frac{n!}{n^n}} < \frac{1}{e} + \varepsilon$

$(\frac{n}{e} - n\varepsilon)^{n} < n! < (\frac{n}{e} + n\varepsilon)^{n}\quad\forall \varepsilon > 0$

Then, we have this well-known inequality (multiple proofs can be found on math.stackexchange):
$$(\frac{n}{e})^{n} < n!$$
So we have:
$$(\frac{n}{e})^{n} < n! < (\frac{n}{e} + n\varepsilon)^{n}$$
According to this inequality, we cannot make $\varepsilon$ arbitrary small, which contradicts the definition of limit.
What am I missing here?

Comment: What do you mean by $\exp$? As far as I know, it's meant to be a function, but you're not giving it an input.

Comment: @CalvinGodfrey, they just mean $e$.

Comment: @Joe In that case $\exp(1)$ would be more accurate.

Comment: @cansomeonehelpmeout, yes that would have been more appropriate. I'm just explaining what OP meant. I absolutely do not condone their notation.

Comment: @mfl, thanks, I was stuck because I didn't consider that all 3 of expressions in this inequality are sequences and thought in terms of fixed **n**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually yes, we can make $\epsilon$ arbitrarily small. Note that your argument is a limit argument, meaning *it doesn't hold for every $n$*. It only holds for all $n \geq N$, where $N$ depends on $\epsilon$.