# Finding $\rho$ for which $(\frac k\rho)^k<\prod\limits_{i=1}^kp_i<((\frac k\rho)+k\varepsilon)^k$

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, prime-numbers

It is known and provable (for instance, it is mentioned [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3069144/fracnen-n-fracne-n-varepsilonn-doesnt-comply-with)), that $$\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^{n} < n! < \left(\left(\frac{n}{e}\right) + n\varepsilon)^{n}\right)$$ for an arbitrarily small $\varepsilon$ and all $n\geq N$, where $N$ depends on $\varepsilon$.

As a first question, it would be great some reference or proof showing that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(\frac{n}{e})^{n}}{n!}=1$$

As a second question, I would like to know if there is known some $\rho$ such that

$$\left(\frac{k}{\rho}\right)^k<\prod_1^{k}{p_{k}}<\left(\left(\frac{k}{\rho}\right)+k\varepsilon \right)^k$$ where $\prod_1^{k}{p_{k}}$ is the product of the first $k$ prime numbers, for an arbitrarily small $\varepsilon$ and all $k\geq N$, where $N$ depends on $\varepsilon$.

I have found no reference to this second question, so any reference would be welcomed.

Thanks!

Comment: You want something slightly different maybe. Did you mean p_k instead of k at the linit?

Comment: @KonstantinosGaitanas I think it is well stated as it is... at least numerical experimentation makes me guess the existence of such a $\rho$. Do you have any argument showing that it can not exist as it is stated?

Comment: By Stirling's formula $n! \sim (\tfrac{n}{e})^n \sqrt{2 \pi n}$, so $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(\frac{n}{e})^n}{n!} = 0$.

Comment: @JuanMoreno You may look up the Chebyshev function $\vartheta(x)$. (cf. $\mathrm{e}^{\vartheta(p_k)}$)

Comment: @Gary thanks for the reference. If I understand well what is stated at [wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_function), $\rho\sim \frac{k}{e}$ and therefore it does not exist some "fixed" $\rho$ as the one asked for in the second question of the OP, right?

Comment: You cannot get an asymptotics for that product because the primes do not behave sufficiently "nicley". It is better to look at the $k$th root of the porduct of the first $k$ primes. Anyway, $p_1 p_2  \cdots p_k  = {\rm e}^{p_k  + E(k)}$ with some error term $E(k)$. Under the Riemann hypothesis $E(k) = \mathcal{O}(p_k^{1/2 + \varepsilon } ) = \mathcal{O}((k\log k)^{1/2 + \varepsilon } )$ with any $\varepsilon>0$.

Comment: By Dusart's results, $$
p_1 p_2  \cdots p_k  = \left( {\frac{{k\log k}}{{\rm e}}} \right)^k {\rm e}^{M(k)} 
$$ with $$
k\frac{{\log \log k - 2.050735}}{{\log k}} \le M(k) \le k\frac{{\log \log k - 2}}{{\log k}}
$$ for $k\ge 10^{11}$. Taking $k$th roots shows  $$
\sqrt[k]{{p_1 p_2  \cdots p_k }} \sim \frac{{k\log k}}{{\rm e}}\sim \frac{p_k}{\mathrm{e}}
$$ as $k\to +\infty$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, by [Stirling's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation)
$$
n! = \left( {\frac{n}{\mathrm{e}}} \right)^n \sqrt {2\pi n} \left( {1 + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{n}} \right)} \right).
$$
This shows that
$$
\frac{{\left( {\frac{n}{\mathrm{e}}} \right)^n }}{{n!}} = \frac{1}{{\sqrt {2\pi n} }}\left( {1 + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{n}} \right)} \right) \to 0 \ne 1
$$
as $n\to +\infty$. It follows that $$
\frac{{\sqrt[n]{{n!}}}}{n} = \frac{1}{\mathrm{e}}\sqrt[{2n}]{{2\pi n}}\left( {1 + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{n}} \right)} \right)^{1/n}  = \frac{1}{\mathrm{e}}\left( {1 + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{{\log n}}{n}} \right)} \right) \to \frac{1}{\mathrm{e}}
$$ as $n\to +\infty$, but this *does not* imply $\frac{n!}{n^n}\sim \mathrm{e}^{-n}$ at all (it cannot be true by Stirling's result).

Regarding the primes,
$$
\log (p_1 p_k  \ldots p_k ) = \vartheta (p_k )
$$
where $\vartheta$ is the first [Chebyshev function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_function). From [this paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2005976), we have
$$
\vartheta (p_k ) = p_k (1 + \mathcal{O}(\exp ( - c\sqrt {\log p_k } ))
$$
with a suitable $c>0$. Cipolla (La determinazione asintotica dell' $n$-esimo numero primo, *Napoli. Rend.*, **8** ($1902$), pp. $132$–$166$) proved more than a century ago that
$$
\log p_k  = \log k + \log \log k + \frac{{\log \log k - 1}}{{\log k}} + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\left( {\frac{{\log \log k}}{{\log k}}} \right)^2 } \right),
$$
$$
\frac{{p_k }}{k} = \log k + \log \log k - 1 + \frac{{\log \log k - 2}}{{\log k}} + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\left( {\frac{{\log \log k}}{{\log k}}} \right)^2 } \right).
$$
Consequently,
$$
\frac{{p_k }}{k} = \log p_k  - 1 + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{{\log k}}} \right) = \log \left( {\frac{{p_k }}{{\rm e}}} \right) + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{{\log k}}} \right) = \log \left( {\frac{{p_k }}{{\rm e}}} \right)\left( {1 + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{{\log ^2 k}}} \right)} \right).
$$
Thus,
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{k}\log (p_1 p_k  \ldots p_k ) &= \log \left( {\frac{{p_k }}{{\rm e}}} \right)\left( {1 + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{{\log ^2 k}}} \right)} \right)(1 +\mathcal{O}(\exp ( - c\sqrt {\log p_k } )) \\ &= \log \left( {\frac{{p_k }}{{\rm e}}} \right)\left( {1 + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{{\log ^2 k}}} \right)} \right)=\log \left( {\frac{{p_k }}{{\rm e}}} \right)+\mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{{\log k}}} \right),
\end{align*}
i.e.,
$$
\sqrt[k]{{p_1 p_k  \ldots p_k }} = \frac{{p_k }}{{\rm e}}\left( {1 + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{{\log k}}} \right)} \right)
$$
where the error term cannot be improved. Since $p_k \sim k\log k$, there is no such $\rho$ you are looking for.

Comment: thanks for your great and complete answer!

Comment: @JuanMoreno You are welcome. Please consider accepting one of the answers provided if you are satisfied with them.

Answer (score 2):

I will only comment on the first question regarding the limit.
Your limit is incorrect. We have
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{ (\frac{n}{e})^n}{n!} = 0.
$$
This property follows from
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{ (\frac{n}{e})^n\sqrt{2\pi n}}{n!} = 1
$$
which is given by [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation).